# Yii: get result for ajax request

Tags: ajax, yii

I have a anchor;

When I click on it, the following code executes:

```
<script>
    $('.viewcnp').click(function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        var r = prompt("Enter your password:");
        if (r) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '<?php echo Yii::app()->baseUrl; ?>' + '/index.php/admin/user/viewCnp/id/' + '<?php echo $model->id; ?>',
                data: {'password': r},
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.cnpdecrypted').text(data);
                },
                dataType: 'text'
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

this code makes a request to this action:

```
public function actionViewCnp($id) {
    $model = User::model()->findByPk($id);
    if ($model) {
        return '{"data":"' . Utils::decrypt_cnp($model->cnp) . '"}';
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

If in the action I echo the cnp decripted, its there, but i can't set the value because I don't receive it on success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply use `echo` instead of `return` :

```
if ($model) {
    echo Utils::decrypt_cnp($model->cnp);
}
```

Comment: perfect solution.i was to post this but u did first.